# How to use QGIS Time Manager sample data?

Tags: python, qgis, time

I've downloaded the [Time Manager plugin](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/an-introduction-to-time-manager-for-qgis/) for QGIS for Windows, version 1.7.1. I'm not sure whether I should really be asking a question on here, but since there doesn't seem to be an issue tracker on the new git, I want to post pictures, and I know the developer frequents this list, I figured I may as well.

My problem is I can't seem to make it work. Using the test data "tweets.shp", I can get an animation, however it is backwards, i.e. the screen is full at the start of the timeline, and tweets are removed at the time they are posted, leaving nothing at the end of the timeline. Graphics attached:

[image: Start of timeline]
[image: End of timeline]

The settings I am using are:

**start**: t

**end**: none

**index**: tweets20120109101002200

**timeformat**: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

**offset**: 0

I installed it manually (due to firewall issues I think) into "*\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python\plugins\timemanager*" - wonder if it's something to do with that.

Alternatively, is there a way I could debug the queries it is making to QGIS for each time point?

Comment: You can see the query in Layer Properties - General. There is also a bug tracker on Github: https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues?sort=created&direction=desc&state=open

Comment: Ah, I thought there might be - I just couldn't see it. IE7, the bane of my life ...

Comment: I wonder if it's not being recongnised as time, as the query is: "t" < '2011-10-09 23:14:57' AND "forever" >= '2011-10-08 23:14:57' , which always seems to fetch 2797 rows, whatever parameters are in "t" and "forever".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the "time step size" to something like 20 seconds (not like the 1 day you show in the screenshots). The tweets test file only covers a short time span of a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for that. What was also throwing me off course was that I was using a text file for the input of my own data. I changed it to a shp and it was fine